# How do you approve allowance for ether spending (not erc20 token)?

Tags: ether, erc-20

With a token you can do token.approve(...)
But how can we do it for ether?

Same question for checking the allowance. It's normally token.allowance(...) for erc20.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard EIP-20 wrapper smart contract for Ether. It is called wrapped ether or WETH.

It is used by decentralized exchanges like 0x relays.

https://weth.io/

To see how it works try some 0x exchanges like Radar.

The downside is that the user needs to convert their ETH to WETH first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for Ether with a custom smart contract. The code would look quite similar to the token code - you just need to be handling Ethers instead of custom tokens.

Something like this:

```
mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
function approve(address spender, uint ethers) public returns (bool success) 
{
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = ethers;
    Approval(msg.sender, spender, ethers);
    return true;
}
```

Similar for other functions. Just remember that the actual withdrawal/transfer doesn't take from `balances` array but from `this.balance`.

Comment: The idea is to give a contract an allowance over an ether account, without pre depositing in the contract. Anytime the contract can call <some-account>.transferFrom(<allowance-account>, ethers).